# Adjust input size according to lenght of text on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

As title says I need to adjust width of input on page load according to text that is called in it with php:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="contact" value="<?php echo "$name"; ?>">
```

Is there a way to get width of text in it and then set width of input?

Thank you!

Comment: You wouldn't really need javascript for this. You could use php to set the length.

Comment: size="<?php echo strlen($name) ?>" just FYI

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on page load with jQuery

```
$(function(){
   $('.contact').attr('size',$('.contact').val().length);
})
```